# What is the better structure between collection and subcollection in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a social `Flutter` app where there is a section for `posts`. Each `post` can have `comments` and each `comment` can have `replies` which are different from `comment` in class level. I am using `Firebase Firestore` as my backend. As the official docs for `Firestore` states that there are three ways to structure our data as follows: top-level collection, document and subcollection (collection inside of a document). In my app, for `posts` I have a top-level collection called `posts` which consists all of the `posts`. Now that each `post` can have thousands of `comments`, so storing `comments` inside each `post` document as a map value is not a good idea as it will cross the limit of 1MB per document and also adding and deleting a `comment` would be so hard. So now I can not decide whether I should create a top-level collection for `comments` or a subcollection for `comments` in each `post` document. It's the same for `replies` of each `comment`. Should I again create another top-level collection for `replies` or a subcollection for `replies` in each `comment` document? I strongly appreciate your advice and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So now I can not decide whether I should create a top-level collection
> for comments or a subcollection for comments in each post document.

There is no difference from a technical or performance perspective since:

1. A Firestore query performance is proportional to the size of your result set, not your data set (i.e. the number of docs in the collection);
2. You can, with [Collection Group queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query), query all the documents of all collections with the same ID (i.e. `comments` or `replies`).

The main difference is probably that in the Firestore console you can easily display the sub-collection of a specific post.

---

Note that if you choose to go for root collections for `comments` or `replies` you should not forget to save the parents IDs in these children docs in such a way you can query the one corresponding to a specific parent.